# Trying to open a new tab with JS with a function

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to call a function in an html to a javascript file with a button and I think the function is going through because the alert is working but the 2nd part of the js file isnt working (This is the part where the javascript opens the new tab.) Please help.

This is my html file. Don't mind the `class="submit_button"` thing. I just cut of my styling. And the rest of my popup.html file.

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input class="URL_Textbox" id="WebsiteName" name="WebsiteURL_Name" placeholder="URL" >
        <input
            type="button"
            class="submit_button"
            onClick="submitFunction()"
            value="Go"
          >
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my javascript file

```
function submitFunction() {
   alert("1234567890")
   location.href("https://www."+document.getElementById('WebsiteURL_Name').value,"_self")
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to respond and read my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **id** should be `WebsiteName`. I suppose, you want to **open** a new browser window with the inserted value. That can be done with [window.open(...)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

```js
function submitFunction() {
  alert("1234567890")
  window.open("https://www." + document.getElementById('WebsiteName').value, "_self")
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input class="URL_Textbox" id="WebsiteName" name="WebsiteURL_Name" placeholder="URL">
    <input type="button" class="submit_button" onClick="submitFunction()" value="Go">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `location.href` this way:

```
location.href = 'someURL';
```

[About Window.location property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```js
function submitFunction() {
   location.href = "https://www." + document.getElementById('WebsiteName').value;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form>
        <input class="URL_Textbox" id="WebsiteName" name="WebsiteURL_Name" placeholder="stackoverflow.com" >
        <input
            type="button"
            class="submit_button"
            onClick="submitFunction()"
            value="Go"
          >
    </form>
</div>
```